# Getting a non-fatal but unexpected error while converting a PHAsset to a UIImage

Tags: ios, swift

I am using this code to convert a `PHAsset` to a full size `UIImage`:

```
func getOriginalAsset(asset: PHAsset, onComplete: @escaping (UIImage?, [AnyHashable: Any]?) -> ()) {
    let manager = PHImageManager.default()
    let option = PHImageRequestOptions()
    option.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true

    manager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: .aspectFit, options: option) { (image, info) in
        onComplete(image, info)
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting this warning from the console every time I try to run this code:

```
[ImageManager] First stage of an opportunistic image request returned a non-table format image, this is not fatal, but it is unexpected
```

**Question**

1. Why do I get this warning?
2. How do I resolve this?

**Update**

Everything works fine when I run this code despite the warning. I just can't stand any warnings/errors in my app (Maybe I'll have to learn to accept it sooner or later)

Comment: I have no idea, but I wouldn't worry about it. Do note, though, that you're going to end up calling `onComplete` _multiple times_ for each image you request, so this may not be the best architecture.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try use this code , I'm add `isSynchronous = true` you can read this document [isSynchronous](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos/phimagerequestoptions/1616945-issynchronous)

I will explain to you the cause of the problem quickly This problem occurs because the opatation  is shown until the end of the image and you request large size images may take time so you should be Thread  in the waiting period until the process of fetching the image

```
func getOriginalAsset(asset: PHAsset, onComplete: @escaping (UIImage?, [AnyHashable: Any]?) -> ()) {
        let manager = PHImageManager.default()
        let option = PHImageRequestOptions()
        option.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
        option.isSynchronous = true 
        manager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: .aspectFit, options: option) { (image, info) in
            onComplete(image, info)
        }
}
```

Comment: This is wrong because making it `isSynchronous` makes scrolling laggy as it needs to wait for every image to return first.